# Python extract week number group by ID and week of year from date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

For each ID I have the dates by one week. I would like to get the `Week_Number` starting from first date and `Week_of_Year` (Sunday is the start of the week).

```
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| ID | Date_Time  | Week_Number | Week_of_Year |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2020-08-16 | 1           | 34           |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2020-08-23 | 2           | 35           |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2020-08-30 | 3           | 36           |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2  | 2020-11-15 | 1           | 47           |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2  | 2020-11-22 | 2           | 48           |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I tried using `strftime`. But it isn't an error.

Code to get Week_of_Year - working

```
df['Week_of_Year'] = df['Date_time'].dt.week
```

Code to get Week_Number - Not working

```
df['Week_Number']=df.groupby(df.Date_time.dt.strftime('%W'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `rank` you can check with `method` which will yield different output when duplicate present.

```
df['Week_Number']=df.groupby('ID')['Week_of_Year'].rank()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `cumcount()`:

```
df['Week_Number']=df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1
```